# ORA-20000 Error when trying to use DBMS_DDL.ALTER_COMPILE

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I am trying to write an anonymous block in PL/SQL
My issue is that I keep getting the ORA-20000 error
IN DBMS_DDL.ALTER_COMPILE('PROCEDURE',NULL ,'object_name');
I have figured out that it does not like the object_name reference, because when I add in a specific name it runs.
My question is how do I reference the object_name column in user_objects to select all object_names in my cursor.
I have added my code for reference.

```
DECLARE

cursor cur_invalid IS
SELECT object_name,status
FROM user_objects
Where object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
AND status = 'INVALID';

invalid cur_invalid%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN cur_invalid;
LOOP
FETCH cur_invalid INTO invalid;
EXIT WHEN cur_invalid%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_DDL.ALTER_COMPILE('PROCEDURE',NULL ,'object_name');
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_invalid;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer the `object_name` with `invalid.object_name` and it should work.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR cur_invalid IS 
      SELECT object_name, 
             status 
      FROM   user_objects 
      WHERE  object_type = 'PROCEDURE' 
             AND status = 'INVALID'; 
    invalid cur_invalid%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN cur_invalid; 
    LOOP 
        FETCH cur_invalid INTO invalid; 
        EXIT WHEN cur_invalid%NOTFOUND; 
        DBMS_DDL.ALTER_COMPILE('PROCEDURE', NULL, invalid.object_name); 
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE cur_invalid; 
END; 
/
```